# Canvas mouse events with requestanimationframe

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a game with the goal to use all canvas.

Currently I have a mouse event for my buttons (mousemove, mousedown, mouseup). Should I just update my canvas-buttons directly from this event or integrate it with requestionanimationframe? I read that a mouse event can be called hundreds of times per second...

Maybe extraneous to the problem: When triggered the event calls objects with buttons to check for mouse position (this is due to only the top-most layer registering mouse events and the way pre-rendering works). Essentially, it's not a 'real' mouse event on each canvas object/button.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's best to update your mouse coordinates at all times (every event trigger), but only act on them every animation frame.

Comment: @somethinghere run an update of the state but wait to draw until the raf comes around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question without knowing more about your game, but in general:

If your game critically relies on the **timing of button presses**, then run your game logic with each `mousedown` (don't wait for rAF). For example, in a shooting game the enemy might move off-target if you wait until rAF to test if the bullet hits the enemy.

If your game relies on the **quantity of button presses regardless of the time**, then just accumulate the `mousedown` count until rAF. For example, in a fast-twitch game you're just testing how many times the user can press your button in response to a prompt.

Either way, put your *display redraws* inside rAF to make the game display as efficiently as possible.